Dump timestamps from the whole filesystem akin to `getfacl -R`
I didn't specify the -N flag when rsyncing data from my old laptop, now all the file birth times are lost.
Can I dump them to a file, and, ideally, restore on the new system too, like it's easily done with getfacl/setfacl?

:C https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669500/129375
